# Python script runs normally but cannot be scheduled

Tags: python, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have a python which can run normally but cannot be scheduled to run successfully on Windows 7 Task scheduler. I even created a batch file to call the python script.

Under the task action ("Start a program"), I have;

```
C:\Backup\backup.bat
```

It is so simple that I cannot find anything that I have done wrong. Anything else that I need to take note?

Comment: What is the status of the task after you've run it? Is the task using the correct startup directory and running with sufficient permissions?

Comment: @Simon MᶜKenzie, I didn't there is a startup directory. C:\Backup is the folder that the batch file resides in. Isn't this enough? When I run the batch file in console, it can run successfully. So, the permissions should be sufficient.

Comment: It is unsafe to believe that the environment and permissions will be consistent between console runs and startup runs. This applies as much to Unix as it does Windows.

Comment: @msw, how do I check the startup environment?

Comment: Why the negative vote? Would like to know what's wrong with the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create on drive C: a directory `Temp` and make sure that security permissions are set to full control for everyone.

Put into your batch file at top:

```
@echo off
echo Current directory: %CD%>C:\Temp\Environment.txt
echo.>>C:\Temp\Environment.txt
echo Environment variables:>>C:\Temp\Environment.txt
echo.>>C:\Temp\Environment.txt
set >>C:\Temp\Environment.txt
```

When you double click on your batch file it writes the current directory to file `C:\Temp\Environment.txt` which will be the directory of the batch file. And it writes all environment variables defined for your user account also to file `C:\Temp\Environment.txt`.

Now rename `Environment.txt` to `DoubleClickedEnvironment.txt`.

Then do what is necessary to run the same batch file as scheduled task and later look on `C:\Temp\Environment.txt`.

You will see most likely by comparing `C:\Temp\Environment.txt` with `C:\Temp\DoubleClickedEnvironment.txt` that the current directory is now `C:\Windows\System32` (respectively `%SystemRoot%\System32`) instead of the directory containing the batch file and the list of environment variables as well as their values differ.

Most important on environment variables are `PATH` and `PATHEXT` when not referencing executables in batch file with name of file with extension and with full path enclosed in double quotes if name or path contains 1 or more spaces. Also all environment variables defined for Python and evaluated by Python are important on your batch file.

Another common mistake on running something as scheduled task is thinking that the used account for the scheduled task has same permissions on accessing files and directories as the current user. This is not the case if the scheduled task is not executed with using your user account.

And last mapped network drives are not mapped on running a batch file as scheduled task. Mapping network drives is done by Windows only on login of a user. So in batch file designed for running as scheduled task

- the UNC paths must be used, or
- the commands **pushd** and **popd** are used to map a network share temporarily to a drive letter using credentials of the account defined for the scheduled task, or
- `%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe X: \\ComputerName\ShareName password /user:domain\username /persistent:no`

  is used at beginning of batch file and

  `%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe X: /delete`

  is used at end of batch file as an example for drive X:.

The last method is very insecure as this makes it possible to everyone with permissions to read the batch file to get user name and password for the share.